Retrieving a single line of HTML code, using GET or similar
I've recently begun teaching myself to code, and am currently working on a very small Python problem I have set myself.
I am using the requests library in Python to retrieve the HTML code from a URL. (Subsequently this data will be further parsed according to specific tags etc. using BeautifulSoup.)
I can do this, and print the retrieved HTML data to screen using the Python script below.
import requests

URL = "https://www.example.com"
page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)

My understanding is that the requests library is making use of the HTTP GET method to retrieve the HTML data.
What I would really like to do, (rather than retrieve the data for the entire page), is to retrieve HTML data from a single line directly. (The content of this line would then be parsed using BeautifulSoup). I'd like to do this
a) see if it's possible.
b) save memory and processing time, as webpages often consist of many lines, and some line are very long!
I was hoping a simple argument to the GET method existed that would refer to the line number of HTML code as it is displayed in the web browser, when viewing the page's source. If so, I could simply state what line number's content I wanted to retrieve.
However looking at the documentation for the GET method, I don't see such a facility.
Failing this route, my next idea is sketchy. I was thinking of using my Python script to cycle through line numbers in the HMTL code until the desired line is reached. However, this defeats the object for me, as I'm trying to avoid retrieving the entire page first.
Before I embark on that action, I'd be grateful for any pointers to other things I might try.

Not possible. You would have to retrieve at least up to the line you're interested in.

You aren't in control over how much of a page is returned to you since you need to send a request to a different server which returns a set response

Also this is not very reliable, because html can change, which may result in line being shifted somewhere

Thanks for all your comments. Much appreciated.
